# Label not being read by screen reader for lightning input field

Tags: lightning-inputfield, label, accessibilty

I'm using a lightning-input-field as a lookup with a custom label. The custom label displays properly and replace the label associated with the field.

My issue is that I want the screen reader to read the custom label `{fieldLabel}`, but it is still reading the field label.

Any thoughts of what to do?

**Edit:** 
Is `lightning-input-field` labelable? If not, is there an alternative?

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={childObjectApiName}>
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="fieldid">{fieldLabel}</label>
        <lightning-input-field id="fieldid" variant="label-hidden" required={required} field-name={targetFieldApiName}
            value={value} onchange={handleChange} disabled={disabled}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Comment: is it reading both the custom label and the input field label?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves It only reads the input field label, I can't get the custom label to be read. I'm using the NVDA screen reader.

Comment: Don't think you'll have an option to override the label for `lightning-input-field`. This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332230/override-the-label-and-helptext-for-a-lightning-input-field) may provide some value.